# Ajax query refreshing whole page instead of part

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have simple View where I have a ajax form I use for filtering records:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", new AjaxOptions()
{

    InsertionMode=InsertionMode.Replace,
    UpdateTargetId="dane"
}))
{

   @Html.Partial("SearchTab") 
}

@Html.Partial("ShowPartial") // <--- id="dane"
```

Partial SearchTab:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-addon name">
                    User name:
                </div>
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-addon surname">
                    User surname:
                </div>
                <input type="text" name="surname" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-addon devicename">
                    Device name:
                </div>
                <input type="text" name="deviceName" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-addon devicemanufacturer">
                    Device Manufactuer:
                </div>
                <input type="text" name="deviceManufacturer" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Filter" id="filter"/>
    <br />
```

Controller action:

```
public ActionResult Index(string name, string surname ,string deviceName, string deviceManufacturer, string Page)
        {
            bool RoleId = ad.CheckIfAdmin(Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name.Substring(Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name.LastIndexOf(@"\") + 1));
            ViewBag.RoleId = RoleId;
            var deviceusages = db.DeviceUsages.Include(d => d.DeviceInstance).Include(d => d.Storage).Include(d => d.User).Where(w=>w.UserId!=6).Skip((int.Parse(Page)-1)*30).Take(30);
            if(name!="" && name!=null)
            {
                deviceusages = deviceusages.Where(w => w.User.Name.Contains(name));
            }
            if (surname != "" && surname != null)
            {
                deviceusages = deviceusages.Where(w => w.User.Surname.Contains(surname));
            }
            if (deviceName != "" && deviceName != null)
            {
                deviceusages = deviceusages.Where(w => w.DeviceInstance.Device.Name.Contains(deviceName));
            }
            if (deviceManufacturer!= "" && deviceManufacturer != null)
            {
                deviceusages = deviceusages.Where(w => w.DeviceInstance.Device.Manufacturer.Contains(deviceManufacturer));
            }
            return View(deviceusages.ToList());
        }
```

After writing something into input field and pressing filter. Ajax should refresh ShowPartial and keep values in the input fields from SerchTab but instead  I get filtered records and inputs are getting empty. Can anyone suggest me edits to change this behaviour

Comment: I used exact your code, but not able to repro your problem, I mean form is persisting its values. I think the problem is not with form elements, you need to check other parts of code.

Comment: I managed to solve my problem. I needed to change code to use Html helpers. Unfortunately I can accept my own answer in two days.

Comment: I think there is no need to change your code to HtmlHelpers. I do not see a reason for changing. But I was wondering how it fixed your problem. Anyways I am glad that you solved your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found cause of a problem.

I need to change this code

```
<div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-addon name">
        User name:
    </div>
    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" />
</div>
```

into same thing made wit use of .net Html helpers.
After this change everything works!

```
@Html.Label("User name: ", new { @class = "input-group-addon" })
@Html.TextBox("name", null, new { @type = "text", @class = "form-control" })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are intending to

```
return View()
```

you should also return the original model so that control values can be populated with your captured values.

Alternatively if you just need to return the list:

```
deviceusages.ToList()
```

Then you can return a PartialView() e.g.;

```
return PartialView(deviceusages.ToList());
```